# How to convert a char arr to a uint8_t array in c for arduino

Tags: c, arrays, arduino

I am trying to pass a string into a function that accepts a `uint8_t *` in c.

This is my attempt, which results in an error:

```
uint8_t data[70];    
char str[70];
sprintf(str,"U,DHT;T,%d;H,%d;I,%d", (int)(ft * 100), (int)(fh * 100), (int)(fi * 100));
strcpy(data,(uint8_t*)str);
```

I get this error though:

```
.ino: In function 'void loop()':
ClimateClient:51: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' to 'char*'
ClimateClient:51: error: initializing argument 1 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
ClimateClient:51: error: invalid conversion from 'uint8_t*' to 'const char*'
ClimateClient:51: error: initializing argument 2 of 'char* strcpy(char*, const char*)'
```

Comment: Use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) instead.